# How to get number of spaces

Tags: php, regex

I have tried to use **preg_match** to match the spaces but it returns one always. How can I get the number of spaces in this string? In this case it should return `8`. Any use PHP function is ok.

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
```

Comment: you don't need  a regex ...

Comment: That's why I asked so that I'll know what function to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you could also use `substr_count` for this:

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
echo substr_count($string, ' '); // 8
```

Comment: great! This works! I'll accept the answer as soon as it'll let me. Thanks

Comment: @JohnRobertson okay man no prob

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
substr_count($text, ' ');
```

substr_count — Count the number of substring occurrences